# How can I effectively test SvelteKit components, including monitoring reactive properties and props passed to child components?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, testing-library, svelte-testing-library

I'm struggling to understand how to effectively test SvelteKit components like this one.

I want to test the `selectedTaxon` property, and one approach is to mock the `TaxonLinkButton` component. However, I'd like to find a more elegant solution. Is there a way to test which props are passed to the `TaxonLinkButton` component? Or is there a way to directly check the reactive property `selectedTaxon` of the component?

What's the best approach? Please feel free to guide me if my testing approach isn't logically correct.

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { page } from '$app/stores';

  import TaxonLinkButton from '../TaxonLinkButton.svelte';

  import type { Taxon } from '$types/product.type';

  export let taxonomies: Taxon[];

  let selectedTaxon: Taxon | null = null;

  $: {
    const permalink = $page.url.pathname.replace(/\/t\//g, '');
    taxonomies.find((taxonomy) => {
      if (taxonomy.permalink === permalink) {
        selectedTaxon = taxonomy;
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
</script>

<div data-testid="test-taxonomy-three-component" class="flex flex-col mt-5 lg:mt-0">
  <TaxonLinkButton {selectedTaxon} >
    {taxonomy.name}
  </TaxonLinkButton>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you test, you can compile the component in dev mode. That way each component will expose an extra `component.$$.hmr_cmp` object, which has a `$capture_state()` getter function that returns the entire local state of the component.

I put together a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ki2cnf?file=src%2FApp.svelte), open console to see log. You can test against `component.$$.hmr_cmp.$capture_state().selectedTaxon` directly.

Comment: ```code
it('does not set the selected taxonomy when the URL does not belong to any taxonomy', async () => {
  const { component } = render(html`<${TaxonomyThree} ...${taxonomyThreeProps({})} />`);

  console.log('@@@###', component.$$); // the result is undefined
  console.log('@@@###', component.$capture_state); // the result is undefined
});
```

as you can see this is not working but I can't understand why.
I have a sveltekit project configured with vite and vitest.

and this is the svelte version: "svelte": "^3.59.2",

Comment: Looks like you're doing some kind of server-side rendering? If you want me to look into it, I'd ask you to provide a reproducible example (preferably a stackblitz project).